# Failed to Install; Program accessing directory android-sdk\platform-tools

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install the Android SDK to retry my shot at development. I'm following the steps at the developer site to install everything for working on Eclipse, but while installing the recommended SDK Platform-tools, I get a warning that a folder failed to be moved. I've closed everything that could possibly be accessing it, but I still get that error. The specific directory that's failing is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools."

I had all of this installed at one point, but uninstalled it because I didn't think I would ever have time to really use it. There were no clear instructions that I could find for uninstalling, so I just did the best I could and cleared out everything I could find. Could it be possible that I missed something in the uninstallation that is messing me reinstall up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uninstall is just deletion of folder. To fix this, restart your pc because I think adb locked that directory making it impossible to remove it. Now, delete that android folder and do a clean install, preferably in a folder that doesn't have spaces in the name. My install is in c:\Android folder.

Answer (score 7):

For the updating Problem after install.

The Android SDK Manager is what is locking the directory. It calls Android.bat in the tools folder to start. If you run Android.bat from command-line with "update sdk" arguments it will run all items from a temp directory and not lock the tools folder.

Change the directory below to your android directory.

"WindowsKey" + "R"

cmd

cd "C:\program files\Android\android-sdk\tools"

android update sdk

OR

In notepad type "android update sdk" without quotes.

Save the file as StartTemp.bat in the tools directory.

Run the bat

Cancel the first screen when it starts, then choose the SDK update version.

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm. Using the command line seems to be quite necessary in Android development... you might try explaining it a bit more for less experienced people.

Comment: I had to shutdown Eclipse and then run the above in cmd..else it still failed. Nonetheless, thank you for the pointer :)

Answer (score 4):

Try installing everything on a path that does not contain spaces, such as `C:\android-sdk`. Stay out of `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and ran the SDK manager as administrator. That worked for me with Vista x64.

Comment: sigh @ Vista.  This was the fix for vista 32 bit as well.

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown Eclipse first, then update the SDK - that worked for me, did not need to stop anti-virus

Answer (score 2):

In the Security tab of Android folder, change the permission of TrustednIstaller to full control.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And here is how I get over that:
make a new copy of the "platform-tools" or "tools" folder and name it for example "tools-bak" then open the new created folder and find a file named "android.bat" double click and continue your setup.