# How to upgrade Android sdk manager

Tags: android

I have download and unzip ADT bundle for Windows 7.

I am trying to upgrade Android sdk, I get the following error saying 
[image]

When I go to task manager to kill my only java process, the whole Android SDK manager got kill.
How can I work around this?

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13686361/3168859)

Comment: Also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102625/failed-to-install-program-accessing-directory-android-sdk-platform-tools)